# How to execute HQL query in Java

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I was wondering if it is possible to execute a HQL query but in Java code. Normally I'd do something like

```
def result = Person.executeQuery('select and so on..')
```

but the `executeQuery` method is added at runtime and not available from Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need access to the `SessionFactory` or a `Session`. If you have the `SessionFactory` it'd be something like

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("select and so on..");
// set parameter values, e.g.
// query.setString("name", "Matthias");
List result = query.list();

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

The transaction is necessary if you execute updates or deletes, and optional for simple selects.

Comment: What's the blessed way of receiving SessionFactory instance? Would it be the org.grails.internal.SESSION_FACTORY_HOLDER? It sounds to me like an awful lot like an internal thing that shouldn't be used outside of the Grails core...

Comment: Depends how you're calling the Java class. If possible it's best to get it from a service/controller/etc. with `def sessionFactory` and pass it to the Java class that's being called.