# How to use groovy domain classes in my Java Project?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have some domain classes in grails application. My middle ware is called as servic

The domain classes would be shared between grails-app and services.

If we use annotation – would services be able to detect them?
How do you share the classes with services ?. Can you do a jar on them?.

Can any one please help me out

Thanks Siva.

Answer (score 0):

You may access your grails domain classes with hql query. See [How to execute HQL query in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777388/how-to-execute-hql-query-in-java) for reference.